# Word 97 Printer Properties crashes

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-word, printing

We are still using Word 97 on Windows XP and we just got a new Canon 8085 printer.  The problem we have is that when we select the printer in Word 97 and click the Properties button, we get a fatal error about some memory location and Word 97 crashes.

However, if we simply click on the print button the toolbar, it prints the document fine.  We can also go to Printer and Faxes, select the printer, and

> Event Type:   Information
>   Event Source: DrWatson
>   Event Category:   None
>   Event ID: 4097
>   Date: 10/29/2012
>   Time: 1:59:59 PM
>   User: N/A
>   Computer: STUDENT
>   Description:
>   The application, C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office\WINWORD.EXE, generated an application error The error occurred on 10/29/2012 @ 13:59:59.281 The exception generated was c0000005 at address 7C913348 (ntdll!wcsicmp)

Comment: It looks like your question is missing some details, just before the event log information.  Could you fill in the missing bits?

Comment: @Iszi You mean the hexadecimal? It's very very long.  Is there a way to spoiler it?

Comment: No, I'm talking about whatever is supposed to finish the sentence "We can also go to Printer and Faxes, select the printer, and..."

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the printer drivers?